# Test for value of specific attribute in all descendant nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XML here:

```xml
<otherNodes>
    <table activateBitmask="true" bitmaskName="Foobar">
        <rowh><col>Foo</col></rowh>
        <row>
            <col>Bar</col>
        </row>
    </table>
</otherNodes>
```

I only want to add a javascript, if the table represents a "bitmask" (activateBitmask="true"). But it's not always a `<table>`-node. So I want to search in all nodes for an attribute `activateBitmask` and see if it's `true`.

```xml
<!-- This runs on <otherNodes> -->
<xsl:if test="descendant::*[@activateBitmask] = true()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="$relpath"/><xsl:text>bitmask.js</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </script>
</xsl:if>
```

At another position `@activateBitmask = true()` works fine so I think the `descendant::*[]` is wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to search in all nodes for an attribute `activateBitmask` and see if it's `true`.

I believe you meant to say:

*"search in all nodes for an attribute `activateBitmask` and see if its string-value is`"true"`"*.

That would be written as:

```
<xsl:if test="descendant::*[@activateBitmask='true']">
```

or shortly:

```
<xsl:if test="//@activateBitmask[.='true']">
```

What you wrote:

```
<xsl:if test="descendant::*[@activateBitmask] = true()">
```

tests the "truthness" of the *element* that is the *parent* of the `activateBitmask` attribute, and will be evaluated as explained in Dr. Kay's answer above.

I will only add that the expression in the `test` attribute of `xsl:if` is always evaluated to a Boolean result, so even in XSLT 1.0 formulating the expression as `some-node = true()` is redundant: a node is true if it exists. However, the node being true is not the same as having the string-value of "true".

Comment: I thought the string `true` would evaluate to a boolean. Thank you for the correction and also for the full solution!

Comment: Well, first of all, you are not evaluating a string, but an attribute (or in your case, an element). And also, any non-zero length string will evaluate as `true`; `boolean('true')` returns the sane result as `boolean('false')`.

Answer (score 2):

With `test="descendant::*[@activateBitmask] = true()"` you're comparing a node-set to a boolean, and the effect of that depends on whether you're running in 1.0-compatible mode (which will be the case if EITHER you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor OR your stylesheet specifies `version="1.0"`).

In 1.0 mode, comparing a node-set to the boolean true returns true if the node-set is non-empty, that is, if there is a descendant element with an `@activateBitmask` attribute.

In 2.0 mode, comparing a node-set to the boolean true returns true if some node in the node-set has a typed value of true -- which will never be the case unless you're running schema-aware XSLT.

It's actually simpler: just write

`test="descendant::*[@activateBitmask]"`

or if you prefer

`test=".//@activateBitmask"`

In both 1.0 and 2.0 mode that returns true if the node-set is non-empty.